# Use parameter as web service input for Informatica mapping

Tags: web-services, informatica

I have a WCF web service that takes a start and end date as input, and returns a record set.  What I'd like to do is setup an Informatica mapping that creates variables for the date from one week ago and today's date.  These are used as input for the web service consumer or web service as a source (whichever will work), but I'm not sure how to go about this.  I can't create an Expression with no inputs, and I don't see how to set a mapped parameter as input.

The only two ways I can think about doing this would be to either build an app that creates a flat file with both dates, or to build a database object that supplies the dates as a source.  I'd rather not have a separate outside source to provide these values, but I can't think of another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the Informatica v9.6.1.  A source has to be created in order to feed the web service.  I ended up creating a dummy record with 1 field, using it as input, then disregarding the input and setting up variable output using an Expression transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need those variables set before mapping run, use `Assignment Task` in the workflow and `use`Pre-session variable assignment` to set the values for the mapping before it runs.

Comment: But how would you use those variables as input?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not get the question. Can you perhaps add some screenshots to illustrate better? Or just explain with more details. I'll do my best to help you out with the problem.